# Crash with android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have a problem related to this statement with ActionBarSherlock:

```
android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

The problem is, If I use this value in a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator">
.....
```

The adapter that contains this XML crash if I use the Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

But it works if I change the theme to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

Is this a bug of ActionBarSherlock?? Or I am doing something wrong? Repeat it crashes If I 
use the Light.DarkActionBar theme but works if I use the Light theme.

I test to change the:

```
android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

for this:

```
 android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Which is the original attribute and works.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1574): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error     inflating class...
....
E/AndroidRuntime( 1574): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:   Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010047 a=-1}
E/AndroidRuntime( 1574): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resource
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to setup a custom `activatedBackgroundIndicator`? If yes the right way is to setup `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`.

Answer (score 0):

I create an issue in the ABS repo and SimonVT said that:

> ABS does not define attributes in the DarkActionBar theme on api14+ that it doesn't use itself. The library isn't meant to help you theme your app.
>   unless ABS uses the attribute we don't set them.

So What I did was to create a layout-v11 folder which that specific layout with:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

And that works... Kind of not really what I want, create a new folder just for one file, but it works.